# When switching the category using the drop down menu the quantity display goes to NaN and cant use increase/decrease function ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have got a drop down selection menu as shown in the image below and when i select first category `Eco-YogaMats`  it fetch  the data using an API and display on the screen and and `add`, `subtract` and `initialquantitiy=0` displays correctly(and can change the quantity) but when next i select the any other category `(Travel-YogaMats)` it displays `add`, `subtract` but the quantity box shows as white square box(if i add/subtract it goes to `NaN`) not sure why it is happening,  it only happens when i switch in the category and it  doesn't happen when i first select the category.
Cant understand the reason behind it, i tried to tweak a bit but didnt help me either, any suggestions please.

```
//addBasketitems  are array of objects of selected Category
function Home({ props, addBasketitems }) {
  let initialQuantities = props.reduce((quantities, product) => ({ ...quantities, [product.product_name]: 0 }), {});

// increase items
const increase = (productName) => {
        setQuantites({ ...quantities, [productName]: quantities[productName] + 1 });
}

// decrease items
const decrease = (productName) => {
    setQuantites({ ...quantities, [productName]: Math.max(0, quantities[productName] - 1) });
  };
```

- and now the return statement that renders on screen

```
     return (
        <div className="products">
          {props.map((eachproduct) => {
            let productName = eachproduct.product_name;
            let producNumber = eachproduct.producNumber;
            let price = eachproduct.price;
            let desc = eachproduct.productDescription;
            let photo = eachproduct.image_URL;
            let stockQuantity = eachproduct.stockQuantity;
            return (
              <div className="products" key={producNumber}>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <img className="products-image" src={photo} />
                  </li>
                  <li>{productName} </li>
                  <li>
                    Item No:{producNumber}(InStock:{stockQuantity})
                  </li>
                  <li>price:{price}£ </li>
                  <li>{desc}</li>
                  <li>
                    <ButtonGroup aria-label="quantityofproduct" key={productName}>
                      <Button variant="secondary" name="subtract" value="subtract" onClick={() => decrease(productName)}>
                        -
                      </Button>
                      <Button name={productName} variant="secondary">
                        {quantities[productName]} // here its showing NaN
                      </Button>
                      <Button variant="secondary" name="add" value="add" onClick={() => increase(productName)}>
                        +
                      </Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>
                    &nbsp;
    <Button
                      name={producNumber}
                      value={quantities[productName]}
                      variant="primary"
                      onClick={() => {
                        addBasketitems(eachproduct, quantities[productName]);
                        clearselection(productName);
                        alert(`${productName}, with quantitiy${quantities[productName]} is added to the basket`);
                      }}
                    >
                      Add to Basket
                    </Button>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

- Sub Category in Menu display (Above photo)
  [image]
- I have made a small `clip` (Below Link)if that helps to understand the issue i am facing.

[[][Video Clip]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2sYXpzE_FI&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update the `initialQuantities` every time the `props` is changed.

```
const [initialQuantities, setInitialQuantities] = useState({}); 

useEffect(() => {
    const newQuantities = props.reduce((quantities, product) => ({ ...quantities, [product.product_name]: 0 }), {});
    setInitialQuantities(newQuantities); 
}, [props]);
```

Or you don't need `initialQuantities`.

```
const [quantities, setQuantities] = useState({}); 
const increase = (productName) => {
    setQuantites({ ...quantities, [productName]: (quantities[productName] || 0) + 1 });
}
// decrease items
const decrease = (productName) => {
    setQuantites({ ...quantities, [productName]: Math.max(0, (quantities[productName] || 0) - 1) });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks it all worked perfectly now. sorry i a bit, i understand useEffect will rerender everytime the [props] is updated /changed, why initialquantities doesn't accommodate the new addition in the list.just to understand  why it didnt work without it. Thanks

Comment: ```[productName]: quantities[productName] + 1```. Here, you're setting ```Undefined``` + 1 as the quantity of the [productName]. So the quantity of the productName becomes ```NaN```